# Read the Meeting Request start time and End time in VSTO outlook plugin

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I am developing a Addin to MS outlook using VSTO c#. There I managed to write a meeting request send event handler.. There I want to get the meeting start time and the end time to pass to a backend server. I searched through the API but i could not find a way to get the meeting start time and the end time. It has other fields such as subject and the body.. 
Can any one tell me how can i achieve this meeting start time and end time using VSTO. Thanx.

```
void OutlookAppItemSend(object item, ref bool cancel)
{
    if (item is Outlook.MeetingItem)
    {
        var appt = item as Outlook.MeetingItem;
        String subject = appt.subject;
        String meetingStartDate= ??????????? 


 }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

[`appt.GetAssociatedAppointment(false).Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff861915.aspx)

and this

[`appt.GetAssociatedAppointment(false).End`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869166.aspx).